# Azure data lake Auto gnerated column in usql

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I want to add a auto generated column in my U-SQL select stamen.
how can we do.

same like identity column in SQL server

Regards,
Manish

Answer (score 1):

The closest would be [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt763822.aspx).  Here is a simple example:

```
@output =
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn,
        *
    FROM @input;
```

You cannot use `ROW_NUMBER` directly with `EXTRACT` at this time.  Simply extract the data first then add the row number in a subsequent section, like this:

```
// Get raw input
@input =
    EXTRACT rawData string
    FROM "/input/yourFile.txt"
    USING Extractors.Tsv();


// Add a row number
@working =
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rn,
           *
    FROM @input;
```

Comment: Thanks it's work with select. can we use in extract also . if I want to use in Extract how can I use